# Resizing div caused bootstrap css to change

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I am just getting started with Asp.net and Bootstrap framework (VS 2015). I noticed that the "row" height property changed in the Bootstrap.css file when I resized the "row" div on the web form. I simply drag the div to make it larger and the height property increased. I see that this can cause issues for other pages.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Please tell me you did not modify the bootstrap stylesheet.

Comment: It is also not a good idea to resize your components/controls directly on the design this can cause a lot of complications for other pages. Instead, use inline CSS it is considered the safest approach to modifying your controls as it only changes the current controls.

Comment: I wouldn't use inline CSS personally as it's not very re-usable and it's hard to maintain. But you could use another custom class in your own styleshsheet to override the row class's height. Certainly I wouldn't modify the bootstrap CSS, or use the visual designer for this (in fact I'd avoid using the visual designer as much as possible and learn to work with the raw HTML, it's much easier to predict what the effects of your changes will be, since you're making them directly.

Comment: First let me say that "I did not modify the Bootstrap stylesheet". I have a custom css class. Second, I am doing all of my development via HTML not the designer. This is a test project, just playing around with ASP.Net using Bootstrap. I noticed that if you resize a div from the designer by dragging it, the property values in the Bootstrap css will change. I am simply pointing out my findings and asking is there a way to prevent the Bootstrap css from changing.